# How to create a read a CSV in NodeJS and create a JSON out of it

Tags: node.js, csv

this is the first time I'm writing NodeJs code. I need small help here. I've a CSV. I want to create a JSON of it.

CSV is simple: **MyData.csv**

[image]

Here is my code:

**csvToJson.js**

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('CareTeamData.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        console.log(row);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });
```

It is giving correct output but the file is not created. Please help me create a file in the same folder itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Array, to hold all the rows of the CSV parsed by csv-parser, Then, on end, write the data to a file.

```js
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");

let results = [];

fs.createReadStream("CareTeamData.csv")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
    .on("end", () => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        fs.writeFile("CareTeamData.json", JSON.stringify(results), (err) =>
            console.error(err)
        );
    });
```